# DatePickerDialog - How to display Day, Month then Year

Tags: android, date, position, show, datepickerdialog

No matter what I do, my DatePickerDialog always displays the month, the day then the year.

Or I need to display the day, the month and then the year.

How can I do that ?

Here is my little code :

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    cal.setTime(date);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, 2, mListenerModifierDate, year, month, day);
    dateDialog.setTitle("Modification de la date d\'intervention");
    dateDialog.setMessage("Choisissez une date égale ou inférieure à aujourd\'hui.");
```

Comment: did you tried to set device locale? i mean global locale from settings? or Settings->Date and time-> Date format?

Comment: Thanks, for me it was (also) a matter of the wrong Date Format being selected in the settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to create you own.  I do not think you can modify the datepickerdialog to display it that way.  Here is the source code to datePickerDialog -> [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java)
and here is the [layout](http://code.google.com/p/date-time-picker/source/browse/DateTimePicker/layout/datepicker.xml?r=5) for datepicker which is called by datepickerdialog.  Just modify your layout and the create your own datepickerdialog class and modify its constructors to use your layout instead.

Comment: Thanks ! That's strange, I've seen many examples where the day was first, with a code like mine. Anyway, I'm going to try your way ;)

Comment: @Lynal I would politely ask, if I resolved your problem correctly that you mark the answer as correct so others can see what solved the problem.  Thank you again

Comment: Ah yes sorry ! I only tried to click on "This anwser was useful" and said that I don't have enough reputation, So i didn't try the mark :p